# android-maven-plugin:3.8.0 requires Maven version 3.1.1

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, android-maven-plugin

I have created an android project using maven archetype. When I try
`clean install` from Intellij Idea, I get the following error.

```
The plugin com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.0 requires Maven version 3.1.1
```

When I try the same thing from a terminal like `$ mvn clean install`, it works fine. When I change the android-maven-plugin to `3.6.0`, it works fine in Idea.

```
My maven version is 3.1.1
```

So, I do not understand why I am even facing this problem with Intellij Idea when I have the android-maven-plugin as 3.8.0. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the error by configuring my IDE to point to right maven version. By default it was pointing to M2_HOME. In Intellij Idea, I did it like

```
File->Settings->Maven
```

and changing the `Maven Home Directory` to point my 3.1.1 installation path.

One way to find your maven home and version would be

```
$ mvn --version
```

You will get something like,

```
Maven home: /usr/share/apache-maven-3.1.1
```